# Git subtree pushes a new tree

Tags: git

I've been working with `git submodules` for a long time and I've been happy about it. My co-workers on the other hand have been complaining about it (and a lot of people in the internet seem to hate `git submodule` as well) and my supervisor decided to change to `git subtree`.

I maintain (together with my supervisor) a project that has 4 `submodules` in it. Every submodule in itself is a stand alone project and has been developed for different projects of our company. Our software has different dependencies on this modules and to help deployment we've created this project that has this 4 submodules.

Now my supervisor created a new branch where he got rid of the submodules and added them using `git subtree`instead. The stand alone repo of one of this ex-sobmodules (let's say `mod1`) looked like this

stand alone repo

```
        D--E--F  dev_feature_X
       /   
A--B--C          master
```

My supervisor used `dev_feature_X` when he added `mod1` with `git subtree`.

Last week I had to fix a feature and I was careful to make separate commits. I wanted to push the changes of `mod1` into it stand alone repository so I executed

```
$ git subtree push --prefix=mod1 user@server:mod1 feature_X
```

On the stand alone repo `mod1` I made a `git fetch` and saw that a new branch was created `origin/feature_X`.

```
  dev_feature_X
              |   
              v   
        D--E--F--P--Q--R  feature_X
       /   
A--B--C                   master
```

This new branch was part of the tree, so I was able to merge it without a problem. I removed the `origin/feature_X` branch because I didn't need it anymore and it was already part of the tree.

Today I had to make a few changes to the big repo again and I was careful again to make separate commits. Once I've pushed my changes I wanted to push the changes of `mod1` to its stand alone repo. So I did again

```
$ git subtree push --prefix=mod1 user@server:mod1 feature_X
```

On the stand alone repo `mod1` I made a `git fetch`, but now `subtree push` pushed a new separate tree

```
           dev_feature_X
                       |   
                       v   
        D--E--F--P--Q--R   A'--B'--C'--...--R'--O feature_X
       /   
A--B--C                   master
```

The content of the commits of this new tree are the same as the commits of the original tree.

What I don't understand is why the first time `git subtree push` pushed only the commits that were "missing" (P, Q, R) but the second time it pushed a whole new tree mirroring the old commits. Now the history is gone, if I merge R with O I get every change of O as an conflict.

Am I missing something or doing it wrong? I've read the man pages and some tutorials and I think I've understood how to do it, but it seems that I'm doing it wrong regardless.